# How to encrypt sql username and password in ConnectionString?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, wpf, security

Connectionstring in c# application has username and password. Is there a way to encrypt this? 
I don’t want to give both username and password in connectionstring as this can be cracked easily.

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very useful requirement for protecting the whole application.Mainly you need to protect the config file.Please follow the link.

[Protecting Connection Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

One way is by using Enterprise Library configuration tool, you can set the Protection provider property for the data access block.